# Jquery mobile and google maps openinfowidow on load and not click

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-map

I'm busy trying to make my info window content on my map marker on the google map I'm using with Jquery Mobile and I find I can't make the infowindow open automatically.

At the moment it opens with a click event, but the load event has no effect.

my current code that works is as follows.

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({
 'center': '-26.083478,28.092296',
 'zoom': 15,
 'disableDefaultUI': true
  }).bind('init', function (ev, map) {
   $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
    'position': '-26.083478,28.092296',
    'icon': 'images/map_logo.png',
    'bounds': false
   }).click(function () {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
     'content': '<div id="siteNotice">' +
     '</div>' +
     '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Lemon Decor</h1>' +
     '<div id="bodyContent">' +
     '<p>Unit 17, Olympia Gardens<br />' +
     'Olympia Street <br />' +
     'Marlboro</p>' +
     '<p> Tel: 011 262 4116<br />' +
     'Fax: 086 697 4110<br />' +
     'Email: <a href="mailto:info@lemondecor.co.za">info@lemondecor.co.za</a></p>' +
     '</div>' +
     '</div>'
   }, this);
 });
});
```

If I change my code to

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({
 'center': '-26.083478,28.092296',
 'zoom': 15,
 'disableDefaultUI': true
 }).bind('init', function (ev, map) {
  $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
   'position': '-26.083478,28.092296',
   'icon': 'images/map_logo.png',
   'bounds': false
 }).load(function () {
  $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
   'content': '<div id="siteNotice">' +
   '</div>' +
   '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Lemon Decor</h1>' +
   '<div id="bodyContent">' +
   '<p>Unit 17, Olympia Gardens<br />' +
   'Olympia Street <br />' +
   'Marlboro</p>' +
   '<p> Tel: 011 262 4116<br />' +
   'Fax: 086 697 4110<br />' +
   'Email: <a href="mailto:info@lemondecor.co.za">info@lemondecor.co.za</a></p>' +
   '</div>' +
   '</div>'
  }, this);
 });
});
```

The load event has no effect.  Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` is not an event method.  It is a method to fire an AJAX request.

If you want to open an infobox when the map has loaded then you will need to to do that once the map has loaded. I haven't used `gmap` but using the google maps api you would do as follows:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    // open info window
});
```